# Call a Scala "val function" from Java gives error

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have a scala val function as follows :

```
  val getTimestampEpochMillis = (year:Int, month:Int, day:Int, hour:Int, quarterHour:Int, minute:Int, seconds:Int) => {
    var tMinutes = minute
    var tSeconds = seconds
    if(minute == 0){
      if(quarterHour == 1){
        tMinutes = 22
        tSeconds = 30
      }else if(quarterHour == 2){
        tMinutes = 37
        tSeconds = 30
      }else if(quarterHour == 3){
        tMinutes = 52
        tSeconds = 30
      }else if(quarterHour == 0){
        tMinutes = 7
        tSeconds = 30
      }
    }

    val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, tMinutes, tSeconds)
    localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT")).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
  }
```

When I am calling this function from Java,
I get the below error:

```
[ERROR]   required: no arguments                                          
[ERROR]   found: int,int,int,int,int,int,int                              
[ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Java code invoking scala val-function:

```
Long minTimestampOfGranularity = getTimestampEpochMillis(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: `getTimestampEpochMillis.apply(..)`

Comment: Thanks..  can u please put it as answer explaining how, why etc..

Comment: Java doesn't use the sugar function syntax, mapping `(..)` to `apply`

Comment: Because functions in Scala are instances of class `Function1`, `Function2`... etc. And these classes have an `apply` method which is called whenever you these functions in Scala. But, you have to explicitly call these `apply` method with Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
getTimestampEpochMillis().apply(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

and note the parenthesis `()` in `getTimestampEpochMillis()`. Examining the generated class using [`javap`](https://mkotsur.github.io/2016-11-04/one-more-thing-to-consider-when-calling-scala-from-java/) we get

```
public scala.Function7<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, scala.runtime.BoxedUnit> getTimestampEpochMillis();
```

where we see `getTimestampEpochMillis()` returns `scala.Function7`, so we first have to call `getTimestampEpochMillis()` before we can `apply` the arguments.